# Especificadores de formato en printf

Tags: c

Por qué esta línea excede los 80 caracteres de ancho de una consola de GNU/Linux o OSX:

```
printf("%16s %16s %16s %16s %16s\n",
           "Artículo", "Cantidad", "Precio unitario", "Descuento", "Total");
```

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo

Comment: no olvides seleccionar alguna respuesta como la adecuada una vez que se han aclarado tus dudas. Veo en tu historial que no lo acostumbras hacer.

Comment: Si tu pregunta fué resuelta te recomiendo señales la respuesta que creas resolvió tu pregunta. Para mas información consulta [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

El especificador de formato de la función

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

tiene el siguiente esquema:

> %[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier

En el ejemplo tienes lo siguiente:

```
printf("%16s %16s %16s %16s %16s\n",
           "Artículo", "Cantidad", "Precio unitario", "Descuento", "Total");
```

Notemos que el especificador de formato que usas es **%16s**. Esto hará que se reserven 16 caracteres por cada argumento adicional **(...)**. Entonces, considerando que en la cadena que tienes como argumento:

```
"%16s %16s %16s %16s %16s\n"
```

se esperan **5** argumentos adicionales, sumando con ello también los **4** (`' '`) espacios que hay especificados en la cadena, esto nos da el total de **84** caracteres.